# There's any problem in not completing the repetitions in trainning?

Tags: weightlifting

Since the start of this year I put a goal to myself, to keep light-lifiting trainning until it's month 6, so it's month 6 and I started to be a bit heavier.
So my question is, my personal trainner at the gym tells me to do, for example, barbell front raise 3 series of 10 repetitions, and I think the weight is cool, not extremely heavy, but my arm can't hold on 10 repetitions so I stop in the moment I think I'll not make it till the end, so I make like 8-7-6 repetitions instead of 10-10-10 as my personal trainner told me.
There's any problem in doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your trainer knows what he's doing, you should be following his advice instead of undermining it by asking us. Your PT knows more about you than we do.

If he says to do 3x10, then that's what you should do. If you're unable to do so, ask him if you should lower the weight, or lower the rep count.